# running multiple freestyle jenkins job as downstream - get build status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```html
node {
    stage('Testing') {
        build job: 'Test1', parameters: [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Foo1')], propogate: false, wait: false
        build job: 'Test2', parameters: [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Bar1')], propogate: false, wait: false
        build job: 'Test3', parameters: [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Baz1')], propogate: false, wait: false
        build job: 'Test4', parameters: [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Foo2')], propogate: false, wait: false
        build job: 'Test5', parameters: [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Bar2')], propogate: false, wait: false
        build job: 'Test6', parameters: [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Baz2')], propogate: false, wait: false
    }
}
```

I have the above job which run multiple freestyle jenkins job in a loop. i have wait false and propogate false so it should not wait for the job to complete and proceed to next job

how can i check the status of the build and if anyone of the job fails i want to make that stage status as unstable

if i try to check the status as below. it says
NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'result' on null object
may be the build is still running and hence cannot check the status .. is there a way to check the status with wait:false and propogate:false

```html
def downstream = build job: TEST1 , wait: false, propagate: false, parameters: parameters)
   if (downstream.getResult() != 'SUCCESS') {
       unstable(message: "Downstream job result is ${downstream.result}")
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually want is to run all the jobs in parallel, and when they all finish check all results and mark the build as `unstable` if one of the jobs failed.

To achieve that you can use the [parallel](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#parallel-execute-in-parallel) keyword to run all you jobs in parallel, for each job set the `wait` property to `true` and when it finishes store its result. Once all jobs finished check all the results to see if one of them failed, if so mark the build as unstable.

Something like:

```groovy
node {
    stage('Testing') {
        // Map of all jobs and their parameters
        def jobs = ['Test1' : [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Foo1')],
                    'Test2' : [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Bar1')],
                    'Test3' : [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Baz1')],
                    'Test4' : [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Foo2')],
                    'Test5' : [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Bar2')],
                    'Test6' : [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Baz2')]]

        // Map to store all results
        def results = [:]

        // Run all jobs in parallel
        parallel jobs.collectEntries { jobName, jobParams->
            ["Running job ${jobName}" : {
                results[jobName] = build job: jobName, parameters: jobParams, propagate: false, wait: true
            }]
        }

        // Check if there are failed jobs
        def failedJobs = results.findAll( it.value.getResult() == 'FAILURE')
        if(failedJobs) { // if there are failed jobs mark build as unstable
            def failedJobNames = failedJobs.collect{ it.key }.join(', ')
            unstable(message: "The following downstream jobs have failed: ${failedJobNames}")
        }
    }
}
```